# SonarQube 7.1 - Debian installation- connection refused

Tags: sonarqube

I'm having trouble with first run of a SonarQube 7.1. I still have an error in logs as below:

`./sonar.sh console`

```
2020.01.16 15:55:24 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{NGq4ygvgSFGtJZHz_LNBIQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}], ignoring...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9001] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:362)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:570)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:351)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:407)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$ScheduledNodeSampler.run(TransportClientNodesService.java:390)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9001
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:632)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

I am trying to run it on Ubuntu 19.10 and Debian 10. Why so obsolete version? Because I have to figure out how to upgrade it to most recent, so I am creating test environment to do so.
Long time ago someone did create current production, since that time no one touched it :)

So far what have been done:
- I've stoped and disabled ufw and iptables
- Java version is almost same like on production.

```
sonarqube@sonarqube-srv:/$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

- sonar configuration looks like this:

```
sonarqube@sonarqube-srv:/$ grep "^[^#;]" /opt/sonarqube-7.1/conf/sonar.properties 
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx2048m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.search.port=9001
sonar.search.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.log.level=DEBUG
sonar.log.level.app=DEBUG
sonar.log.level.web=DEBUG
sonar.log.level.ce=DEBUG
sonar.log.level.es=DEBUG
sonar.log.rollingPolicy=time:yyyy-MM-dd
sonar.log.maxFiles=7
sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true
sonar.telemetry.enable=false
```

When I run `./sonar.sh start` insead of `./sonar.sh console` I get an error like this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe83110eb21, pid=5723, tid=0x00007fe848814700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 21 C1 java.lang.String.getChars(II[CI)V (62 bytes) @ 0x00007fe83110eb21 [0x00007fe83110eb00+0x21]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/sonarqube-7.1/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid5723.log
```

Does anyone knows what I'm I missing?

Comment: You are using port 9001. In the config you can read: "# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port. # As a security precaution, should be blocked by a firewall and not exposed to the Internet." Maybe something is changed in a firewall or maybe you are running sonaqube as root which is not allowed.

Comment: changing port setting from 9001 to 0 changes nothing. Still same error:

```
jvm 1    | 2020.01.20 14:50:34 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{7wuCGfkIRQmuK9Q1BBQv4g}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:34459}], ignoring...
jvm 1    | org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:34459] connect_timeout[30s]
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:362)
```

And I am running it as a sonarqube user- not as a root.